# Random crashes in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this app in the app store, which according to Crashalitics, its %92-%95 stable. I made a similar app for Android and its around 98% stable. I am trying to get the stability up - but I don't see how. All the bugs I am seeing in the IOS version are not touching my code.

I see random bugs, that are not reproducible, and when they do are *very* random. Each happens 1-10 times, but I have a list of ... ~30 different items.

The app is pretty simple - a mostly linear storyboard (a few jumps, but no loops). The only project I am using which is not Apple's code is InAppSettingsKit, and most of the app is just maps which shows some items. The project is using ARC and currently compiled using XCode6 (but XCode5 showed the same symptoms).

How can I find these crashes? Is this in an inherent problem of IOS7-8? I do see some apps just closing up when I use the IPhone, and friends to tell me that IOS is not that stable, but ... I just think **I** am doing something wrong.

***IOS8 70% IOS7 30%***

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x36444f66 objc_msgSend + 5
1  UIKit                          0x2c160b35 -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _delegateScrollViewAnimationEnded] + 52
2  UIKit                          0x2c160ac1 -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _scrollViewAnimationEnded:finished:] + 184
3  UIKit                          0x2c20a5e5 -[UIAnimator stopAnimation:] + 476
4  UIKit                          0x2c209fb9 -[UIAnimator(Static) _advanceAnimationsOfType:withTimestamp:] + 304
5  UIKit                          0x2c209e85 -[UIAnimator(Static) _LCDHeartbeatCallback:] + 52
6  QuartzCore                     0x2bae4aeb CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 98
7  QuartzCore                     0x2bae4953 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 366
8  IOMobileFramebuffer            0x303c482f IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 90
9  IOKit                          0x29af01ed IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 256
10 CoreFoundation                 0x28b7c3a5 __CFMachPortPerform + 132
11 CoreFoundation                 0x28b8c7f3 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
12 CoreFoundation                 0x28b8c78f __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 346
13 CoreFoundation                 0x28b8adb1 __CFRunLoopRun + 1608
14 CoreFoundation                 0x28ad7b31 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
15 CoreFoundation                 0x28ad7943 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
16 GraphicsServices               0x2feb7051 GSEventRunModal + 136
17 UIKit                          0x2c0cd6f1 UIApplicationMain + 1440
18 ---------------                0x000c8833 main (main.m:16)
```

***IOS7 - 8 times***

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x2e23ef83 __exceptionPreprocess + 130
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x389efccf objc_exception_throw + 38
2  CoreFoundation                 0x2e242917 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 202
3  CoreFoundation                 0x2e241203 ___forwarding___ + 706
4  CoreFoundation                 0x2e190768 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
5  VectorKit                      0x35ec6911 -[VKMapCanvas initShouldRasterize:contentScale:inBackground:] + 476
6  VectorKit                      0x35ec620f -[VKMapView initWithGlobe:shouldRasterize:inBackground:] + 230
7  MapKit                         0x2f3d980b -[MKBasicMapView initWithFrame:andGlobe:shouldRasterize:] + 322
8  MapKit                         0x2f40cd77 -[MKMapView _commonInitAndEnableLoading:fromIB:gestureRecognizerHostView:showsAttribution:] + 878
9  MapKit                         0x2f40d86b -[MKMapView initWithCoder:] + 134
10 UIKit                          0x30e70169 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 740
11 UIKit                          0x30e6fe7f -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 90
12 UIKit                          0x30dcb5ff -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 150
13 UIKit                          0x30e70169 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 740
14 UIKit                          0x30e70109 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 644
15 UIKit                          0x30e6fe7f -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 90
16 UIKit                          0x30dcadd1 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 888
17 UIKit                          0x30d2360b -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 234
18 UIKit                          0x30b7fbcd -[UIViewController loadView] + 92
19 UIKit                          0x30a602ed -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 72
20 UIKit                          0x30a60269 -[UIViewController view] + 24
21 UIKit                          0x30b0a14b -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 198
22 UIKit                          0x30b09dfd -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 572
23 UIKit                          0x30b09b6d -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 44
24 UIKit                          0x30b09b05 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 184
25 UIKit                          0x30a5bd59 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 380
26 QuartzCore                     0x306d962b -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 142
27 QuartzCore                     0x306d4e3b CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 350
28 QuartzCore                     0x30703cdd -[CALayer layoutIfNeeded] + 140
29 UIKit                          0x30ad8163 -[UIViewController window:setupWithInterfaceOrientation:] + 242
30 UIKit                          0x30ad6783 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 3498
31 UIKit                          0x30ad59d3 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 46
32 UIKit                          0x30ad595b -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 94
33 UIKit                          0x30ad58f3 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:duration:force:] + 42
34 UIKit                          0x30acdf69 __57-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]_block_invoke + 108
35 UIKit                          0x30a62107 -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 382
36 UIKit                          0x30ad5641 -[UIWindow setAutorotates:forceUpdateInterfaceOrientation:] + 696
37 UIKit                          0x30ad5105 -[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 164
38 UIKit                          0x30a67045 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 460
39 UIKit                          0x30a64827 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 302
40 UIKit                          0x30ace33d -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 60
41 UIKit                          0x30acafad -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1820
42 UIKit                          0x30ac556b -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 714
43 UIKit                          0x30a616e9 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3540
44 UIKit                          0x30a60851 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 72
45 UIKit                          0x30ac4ca9 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 616
46 GraphicsServices               0x33079aed _PurpleEventCallback + 608
47 GraphicsServices               0x330796d7 PurpleEventCallback + 34
48 CoreFoundation                 0x2e209a67 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
49 CoreFoundation                 0x2e209a03 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 346
50 CoreFoundation                 0x2e2081d7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1398
51 CoreFoundation                 0x2e172ebf CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
52 CoreFoundation                 0x2e172ca3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
53 UIKit                          0x30ac3ed1 -[UIApplication _run] + 760
54 UIKit                          0x30abf14d UIApplicationMain + 1136
55 ---------------                0x000ef833 main (main.m:16)
56 libdyld.dylib                  0x38efcab7 start + 2
```

***Another (IOS 6.1.6)***

```
vThread : Fatal Exception: NSGenericException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x31eaf2a3 __exceptionPreprocess + 162
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x39b0b97f objc_exception_throw + 30
2  UIKit                          0x3404d30f -[UIStoryboardPushSegue perform] + 1118
3  UIKit                          0x33da20c5 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 72
4  UIKit                          0x33da214d -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 120
5  UIKit                          0x33da20c5 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 72
6  UIKit                          0x33da2077 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 30
7  UIKit                          0x33da2055 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44
8  UIKit                          0x33da190b -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 502
9  UIKit                          0x33da1e01 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 488
10 UIKit                          0x33cca5f1 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 524
11 UIKit                          0x33cb7801 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 380
12 UIKit                          0x33cb711b _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6154
13 GraphicsServices               0x359735a3 _PurpleEventCallback + 590
14 GraphicsServices               0x359731d3 PurpleEventCallback + 34
15 CoreFoundation                 0x31e84173 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
16 CoreFoundation                 0x31e84117 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 138
17 CoreFoundation                 0x31e82f99 __CFRunLoopRun + 1384
18 CoreFoundation                 0x31df5ebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
19 CoreFoundation                 0x31df5d49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
20 GraphicsServices               0x359722eb GSEventRunModal + 74
21 UIKit                          0x33d0b301 UIApplicationMain + 1120
22 ---------------                0x00116833 main (main.m:16)
23 libdyld.dylib                  0x39f42b20 start
```

Comment: You could try putting in some more logging which might help zero-in on the problematic areas. The second log message you've pasted tells me that sometime after you initialize `VKMapCanvas`, you're sending a message to an object that doesn't recognize the message.

Comment: That is my exact problem - I none of my code is in this path (look, all IOS): I don't know where to put logs.  I also have a lot of exc_bad_access kern_invalid_address coming from "random places". This smells like a problem hiding - but I don't know where.

Comment: The first two traces you show are possibly caused by providing delegate objects that then are being released too early.  If you were dealing with a normal crash log, there might be more detail in the header section about the object or (in the second case) the selector but I don't know if that's available through Crashalitics.  But I think your intuition is correct: this isn't iOS doing bad things to you.

Comment: Another question is whether Crashalitics can get you device console logs.  Those might have useful messages.

Comment: ahm... so... as an IOS n00b.. I need to ask... how come I never see those crashes on my emulators/phones? Why aren't those reproducible "always"? (I feel this question is moving outside the scope of this site).

Comment: Frequently, the difference is timing, or the interaction of multiple threads, or a specific sequence of actions.  Though I'm guessing, consider that the first one mentions the end of an animation.  That can take a variable amount of time and who knows whether the delegate it wants to call has been released on a different thread by the time that happens...or in response to an earlier event.  If you can reproduce any of these, turn on zombies in your scheme to get better information.  For logging, try printing something in a `dealloc` of any object you use as a delegate.